# what us the best practice to create persistence array in IOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

usually in `Android` I use `</string-array name="">` tag in `.xml` file and refer to it inside the code by its name.

what is the best practice to create an array in `IOS` that I can use in multiple views without having to create it over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what values you want to store in your array and if you want to persist if you need to write into the array and persist it between app runs as well, you have several methods.

1. Store the array in UserDefaults. You can read from/write to [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) from each of your ViewControllers and your data will be persisted even if the user quits the app.
2. Store it in a file. I wouldn't really recommend this option, unless you have a lot of data to store that can be easily represented as String/NSData.
3. Store data in a shared, singleton variable. This method is only suitable if you don't want to write into your array or you don't need to persist it between runs.
4. Use a database framework (CoreData or Realm). This is only recommended, if you have really complex data, but since you mentioned only an array, this shouldn't be your case.

Based on the amount of information provided in your question, I would suggest going for UserDefaults, it is quite easy to handle data in UserDefaults and it should be sufficient for your task.

Comment: The values are fixed to all users, they won't be changed.

Comment: In that case, storing the array as a singleton (static variable) might be even easier than UserDefaults.